# Centralised NSS backend for Linux

Tags: linux, user-management

I'm looking to centralise user management for a pool of Linux servers.

I have previously done this using [libnss-mysql](http://libnss-mysql.sourceforge.net/) which worked ok. However, the project has not been updated since 2006 which concerns me.

As this is a new setup I've got a free choice of the backend to use - MySQL, LDAP, Postgres, whatever. What back-end and NSS library do people recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to use LDAP as access protocol for such a user-management.

For simple requirements you can

- setup your own custom LDAP server with appropriate schema
- use MS Active Directory preferrably with *sssd*

You can use one of the usual LDAP-NSS/PAM integration components which are pretty mature today (in no particular order):

- [sssd](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd)
- [nss-pam-ldap](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) also known as *nslcd*

For more complex requirements, e.g. authorization based on host groups, you may want to use full-featured solutions more dedicated to Linux/Unix:

- [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org) using [389-DS](http://www.port389.org/) as back-end, preferably with *sssd*
- [Æ-DIR](https://www.ae-dir.com/) using [OpenLDAP](https://www.openldap.org) as back-end, with any NSS/PAM implementation for LDAP, or in large setups preferably with [aehostd](https://ae-dir.com/aehostd.html)

Full disclosure: I'm the project maintainer behind Æ-DIR and therefore I'm biased of course.